# Generalized async data loading via ValueTask in EF

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a base class for all my entities in entity framework, it provides general properties (e.g. id, change/creation date)

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime? ChangeDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to check some entities (their database table) for changes, to this extend I wrote a class that periodically compares all the available ids and their change date (from base entity) to the ids/dates from a previous load.

This got complicated pretty fast as I am not too deep into generics and handling them. I use the following dictionary to store tracked types and related data/info:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, ObservingEntity> _observingEntities;
```

Where the ObservingEntity class is:

```
public class ObservingEntity
{
    public Type EntityType { get; set; }
    
    public HashSet<Action<Dictionary<Type, BaseEntity[]>>> Callbacks { get; set; }
    
    public ImmutableHashSet<(int, DateTime?)> LatestDataMeta { get; set; }
    
    public MethodInfo RepositoryGetterReference { get; set; }

    public ObservingEntity(Type entityType)
    {
        EntityType = entityType;
        Callbacks = new HashSet<Action<Dictionary<Type, BaseEntity[]>>>();
        var getter = typeof(IReadRepository).GetMethod("GetAll");
        RepositoryGetterReference = getter.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
    }
}
```

You can already see that I am using a method reference to execute the `IRepository.GetAll<TrackingType>` method since I do not know the type at compile time. Repository method:

```
public async Task<T[]> GetAll<T>() where T : BaseEntity
{
    return await _context.Set<T>()
        .ToArrayAsync();
}
```

And here is where to real fun begins; this is the code being executed periodically to load the data:

```
foreach (var entityEntry in _observingEntities)
{
    var task = (Task)entityEntry.Value.RepositoryGetterReference.Invoke(_repository, null);
    await task;
    var currentData = (BaseEntity[])((dynamic)task).Result;
}
```

This does work - however I think it is overcomplicated and dislike the use of `Task` vs `ValueTask`.
`Task<UnknownTrackingType>` can be cast to `Task` without problems but since `ValueTask` is a struct it seems the same is not possible (cast `ValueTask<UnknownTrackingType>` to `ValueTask`). I am interested in this because I would like to avoid the additional Task allocation.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a more elegant way to execute `GetAll<Typed>` on my repository than using a typed `MethodInfo` reference and `await` the result using a `dynamic` cast (to access the result)?
2. How could I use `ValueTask<>` instead of `Task<>` to avoid the allocation?

I would like to avoid reflection and performance problematic code to establish something that comes close to a best practice solution.

Comment: Changing `Task` to `ValueTak` will not give you serious benefits, since you load full tables into memory. I think better here to explain why this approach appear.

Comment: It would just be "nice" to avoid the extra overhead, but you are right, in real usage this will most likely result in non-mesurable benefit.